# Understanding かかわってくる

Tags: grammar

> 「進級するにあたっては、一般教養の単位も必要だが、各学科の個別課題の提出率も大きく**かかわってくる**」

I understand that the speaker is saying the 提出率 matters a great deal when it comes to 進級. But why is there a くる added to 関わる? Does the くる mean something? Can we just use 関わる in this sentence?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/677/30454  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3160  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/84325

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of -てくる used to describe something that *psychologically* comes towards you. 関わってくる typically refers to something that becomes more and more important over time, but here it refers to something that may not seem important at first but will turn out to be important later. One of the ways to translate this 関わってくる would be "to *come* into play".

See: [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about each item's translations but it brings more or less the nuance that "although standard school credits are important, what each individual did on their own in their own specialty *also comes into play* when talking about promotion."

The くる is simply the idea of bringing something new on the table, which here is the fact that individual contributions matter.